# whole DNA file Slice to a fixed length substring by index/location

Tags: python, slice, sequences

I am new to python, I am writing code to slice a DNA sequence.
the idea is to : firstly to count the sequence length in the text file, secondly, to slice the sequence into substrings with length of 5. and finally to write each substring in a line in output text file.

I couldn't figure out how to split the sequence from each character with the same length, let us say the text file contain [ACTGTATGCATACACGTA...] the results should be like ACTGT , CTGTA, TGTAT, ...

I need help with the incremental loop function that can help to split/slice by index/location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
st = "ACTGTATGCATACACGTA"
for i in range(0,len(st[:-4])):
    print(st[i:i+5])
```

O/P will be like :

```
ACTGT CTGTA TGTAT GTATG TATGC ATGCA TGCAT GCATA CATAC ATACA TACAC ACACG CACGT ACGTA
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikas Damodar, while the DNA sequence is very long, this method is working with small problem, after around 65 letters/slice i start to lose the fixed length for around 35 slice. in frequent for the whole file, any advice

Answer (score 0):

Use `textwrap` to split input string to chunks and then write them to `newfile.txt`:

```
import textwrap

s = 'ACTGTATGCATACACACTGT'  # your input DNA sequence
splitted = textwrap.wrap(s, 5)  # split it to 5-char substrings

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as f:  # write to a text file
    for line in splitted:
        f.write(line + '\n')  # one substring = one line
```

Output file:

```
ACTGT
ATGCA
TACAC
ACTGT
```